# simple summation example and simplyfing it

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, summation

How this summation is near to $ \frac{n}{2}$.

$ \frac {1+2+3+4+...+(n-1)+(n-1)}{n} \sim \frac{n}{2} $

Comment: $1+2+\cdots+n=n(n+1)/2$.

Comment: Arrange the terms in pairs $(1,n),(2,n-1),...$ like Gauss did as $n+1=1+n=2+(n-1)=\cdots$. Count the number of pairs there. Or prove it by induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}\frac{1+2+\cdots+(n-1)+(n-1)}{n}&=\frac{[1+2+\cdots+(n-1)+n]-1}{n} \\
&=\frac{[n(n+1)/2]-1}{n} \\
&=\frac{n+1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\sim\frac{n}{2}.\end{align*}